# PyCharm gives me warnings when it doesn't seem to warrant it, in particular with @lazy and NumPy

Tags: pycharm

Frequently, PyCharm seems to give me warnings when it doesn't seem warranted. Is this a problem inherent with PyCharm or my settings? (or the nature of a dynamically types language?)

In particular, whenever we use `@lazy`, from the lazy package, PyCharm states `'lazy' is not callable`. When we use a np.log, PyCharm can't find that (FYI it's imported in the numpy package as `import * from`). Or when we take a pandas Series and do an operation using arithmetic operators (`* / + -`), PyCharm treats it as a float.

It runs absolutely fine - this is just the warnings while coding.

Thanks,
Max